# How to get/compute total number of months using JDateChooser

Tags: java, swing, jdatechooser

I'm new to Java

How do I get the total number of months between two (2) jdatechooser? I've search already about this but the date was set to the code, In my case I want to put the dates via JDateChooser.

I can do this through this code but if the year change I was not able to compute the total number of months I want to do this without using `JodaTime`.

Here is my code

```
    public void month(){
    int TotalMonth;
    Calendar toDate;
    Calendar fromDate; 
    int increment;

    Date dt1 = date1.getDate(); //datechooser 1
    Date dt2 = date2.getDate(); //datechooser 2



    fromDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    toDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    if(dt1.after(dt2))
    {
        fromDate.setTime(dt2);
        toDate.setTime(dt1);
    }
    else
    {
        fromDate.setTime(dt1);
        toDate.setTime(dt2);
    }
    increment = 0;

    TotalMonth = toDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) - (fromDate.get(Calendar.MONTH +  increment));

    jLabel2.setText(Integer.toString(age));

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`JodaTime` is simpler, however...

You need to loop from the start time to the end, incrementing the `MONTH` field on each loop while the date remains before the end time...

For example...

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTime(sdf.parse("08/03/1972"));
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal2.setTime(sdf.parse("08/03/2014"));

    // Yes, you can use cal1, but I you might want
    // to preserve it for other reasons...
    Calendar cal3 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal3.setTime(cal1.getTime());
    int months = 0;
    while (cal3.before(cal2)) {
        cal3.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        months++;
    }

    System.out.println("Months = " + months);

} catch (ParseException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Prints out `Months = 505`.

If you change `cal2` to `08/04/1972`, it will print `Months = 1`